# why does the checkbox slider does not works with mouse?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the following dataTable element:

```
<div id="searchable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline" role="grid">
    <table id="termGridParametersTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped dataTable" aria-describedby="searchable_info">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th th:text="#{gen.code}" />
                <th th:text="#{gen.desc}" />
                <th th:text="#{termGrid.paramType}" />
                <th th:text="#{termGrid.paramValue}" />
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="gridEffectiveParam : ${effectivePojo.effectiveParameters}">
                <td th:text="${gridEffectiveParam.parameter.code}" />
                <td th:text="${gridEffectiveParam.parameter.description}" />
                <td th:text="#{'termGrid.' + ${gridEffectiveParam.parameter.contractParameterType}}" />
                <td>

                    <th:block th:if="${#strings.equals(gridEffectiveParam.parameterType,'paramType.boolean')}">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="booleanValue" th:onchange="'updateValue(\'' + ${gridEffectiveParam.id} + '\', this);'" th:checked="${gridEffectiveParam.booleanValue}" class="checkbox-slider colored-darkorange" />
                        <span class="text"></span>
                    </th:block>

                    <th:block th:if="${#strings.equals(gridEffectiveParam.parameterType,'paramType.float')}">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="floatValue" th:onblur="'updateValue(\'' + ${gridEffectiveParam.id} + '\', this);'" th:value="${gridEffectiveParam.value}" />
                    </th:block>

                    <th:block th:if="${#strings.equals(gridEffectiveParam.parameterType,'paramType.integer')}">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="intValue" th:onblur="'updateValue(\'' + ${gridEffectiveParam.id} + '\', this);'" th:value="${gridEffectiveParam.value}" />
                    </th:block>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The `updateValue()` javascript function is working nicely and follows:

```
function updateValue(id,value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "updateEffectiveParameter?id=" + id + "&value=" + value.value,
    type: "GET",
    datatype:"json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json', 
    success: function(response){
        if(!response){
            bootbox.alert("a problem occured");
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert('error message');
    }
});
```

But I can only change the checkbox-slider value by hitting `TAB` from the previous field and hitting the space bar. No mouse select.

I understand this has something to do with the [DataTables JS component](https://datatables.net/).

What's the problem here and how to get it working?

Comment: Behaviour is the same on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `th:onchange` for first checkbox and `th:onblur` for second and third checkbox. I guess you need to use `th:onchange` in all three.